# The list of running daemons

Tags: administration

How to get the list of daemons and theirs statuses (stopped, running, crashed, etc) for each runlevel? Like `rc-status` in gentoo.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run `service --status-all` to get a list off all the Upstart services and their status. (It basically issues a `status` command for all the services.)

Comment: I think ```service --status-all``` is for sysvinit managed daemons (as the service command comes from the sysvinit-utils package). The ones managed by Upstart can be seen with ```initctl list```

Comment: `initctl list` seems better because it list out all, where some not in `service --status-all`. Eg. dovecot, vsftpd etc. @yuvilio if you post as answer i would definitely +1 it.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 TLS and initctl doesn't seem to be installed. Was this replaced by something?